# Is it posible to update a label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, label, tk-toolkit

I made a program that could find square roots, but I noticed when finding the square root of 3 and then 4, that it didn't change the label, instead it made a new one on top of the old one (see pics).
This is how my code looks:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

def getSquareRoot ():  
    x1 = entry1.get()
    
    label1 = tk.Label(root, text= float(x1)**0.5)
    canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=label1)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Get the Square Root', command=getSquareRoot)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

[This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjTsk.png)

Comment: This can be answered by reading available documentation. It's not clear why you need our help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only have 1 label that you should update with the result as it comes in like this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root= tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 300)
canvas1.pack()

entry1 = tk.Entry (root) 
canvas1.create_window(200, 140, window=entry1)

# Create the results label
results_label = tk.Label(root)
canvas1.create_window(200, 230, window=results_label)

def getSquareRoot():
    x1 = entry1.get()
    # Update the label with the new result:
    results_label.config(text=float(x1)**0.5)
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='Get the Square Root', command=getSquareRoot)
canvas1.create_window(200, 180, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @GideonLyhne If this is the answer you were looking for, please accept it so other people don't waste time answering your question.

Comment: @TheLizzard Smart Fellow, eh? xD